# How to call Timer() call in 1 second 30 timer in swift

Tags: swift

```
var timer = Timer()
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:Selector("videosecondcounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

i want to call timer 30 time in 1 second please help me

Answer (score 0):

**This way you can run the timer 30 times in 1 second. After it is run 30 times, it will automatically be stopped**

```
// Timer That will be monitored
var myTimerToRepeat:Timer?
/// Number of times Timer ran
private var myTimerRunCount:Int?
/// Number of times Timer need to Run
private var numOfRepeatition:Int?
/// Time Interval for how long timer need to run
var myTimeInterval : TimeInterval = 1


/// Timer Handler
@objc func repeatTimerValue() {
    myTimerRunCount!+=1
    print("Repeat Count \(myTimerRunCount!)")
    /// Check is Timer Ran Max ?
    if myTimerRunCount! == self.numOfRepeatition! {
        /// yes Stop
        myTimerToRepeat!.invalidate()
        myTimerToRepeat=nil
    }
}

/// Start Timer
func startTimer(WithInterval Inter: TimeInterval) {
    if myTimerToRepeat != nil {
        myTimerToRepeat!.invalidate()
        myTimerToRepeat=nil
    }
        /// Start Timer
        myTimerToRepeat = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Inter, target: self, selector: #selector(repeatTimerValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /// Set Count to 0
    myTimerRunCount=0
    /// Set the num of Repeatitions
    numOfRepeatition=30
    /// Start Timer
    startTimer(WithInterval: myTimeInterval/Double(numOfRepeatition!))
    }
```